# Flyway 4.0 Oracle Tablespace

Tags: oracle11g, flyway

I didn't see any means to set the tablespace for Oracle schema generation.  Is that feature available?  I'm getting around it now by using an afterMigration sql to move the schema meta data table and rebuild its index on the desired tablespace.

The items below seem to concern this issue:

- https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/98
- https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/865

Comment: If you want to do this to create a separate tablespace for indexes and data, don't bother.  Using more than one tablespace for an application is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: There are implementation constraints that require  separate tablespaces for both. They can't be changed.  In any case, I'd like to at least choose one tablespace.  In my situation flyway can create the schema.  It uses the default tablespace of the database, which is not the one I want.